Format of generated .HSX file?
.HSX file in Siesta
Where can I find info about the format of the output file .HSX file generated by Siesta

+1. Welcome to our community.

Siesta has evolved the HSX file format since 4.1 and up to the latest (as of now) 5.0 release.
As such it is simplest to look at the source code of the release you are currently working with.
I would suggest you to look into the utility Util/HSX which contains information on how to read/write the HSX file format. For explicit details, read the source code of hsx_m.f90 which contains the logic for reading the file.
Alternatively, if you just want to play with the Hamiltonian, you can use sisl as an IO parser.
Disclaimer: I am the author of sisl

@BoHellsing could you please mark this answer as correct if you found your question answered, if not, please tell us what is needed?
